# Error when using Keras for transfer learning: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: python, keras, image-recognition, keras-2

I am getting following error

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'

when running the following script which uses transfer learning in Keras to retrain and fine tune the last layer in the Inception V3 model.  For my dataset I'm using [Kaggle's Cats and Dogs](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats/data): I'm still new to Keras so your help is much appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
import os
import sys
import glob
import argparse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from keras import __version__
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3, preprocess_input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.optimizers import SGD


IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT = 299, 299 #fixed size for InceptionV3
EPOCHS = 3
BAT_SIZE = 32
FC_SIZE = 1024
NB_IV3_LAYERS_TO_FREEZE = 172
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 780

def get_nb_files(directory):
  """Get number of files by searching directory recursively"""
  if not os.path.exists(directory):
    return 0
  cnt = 0
  for r, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for dr in dirs:
      cnt += len(glob.glob(os.path.join(r, dr + "/*")))
  return cnt


def setup_to_transfer_learn(model, base_model):
  """Freeze all layers and compile the model"""
  for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
  model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


def add_new_last_layer(base_model, nb_classes):
  """Add last layer to the convnet
  Args:
    base_model: keras model excluding top
    nb_classes: # of classes
  Returns:
    new keras model with last layer
  """
  x = base_model.outputs
  x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
  x = Dense(FC_SIZE, activation='relu')(x) #new FC layer, random init
  predictions = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')(x) #new softmax layer
  model = Model(inputs=base_model.inputs, outputs=predictions)
  return model


def setup_to_finetune(model):
  """Freeze the bottom NB_IV3_LAYERS and retrain the remaining top layers.
  note: NB_IV3_LAYERS corresponds to the top 2 inception blocks in the inceptionv3 arch
  Args:
    model: keras model
  """
  for layer in model.layers[:NB_IV3_LAYERS_TO_FREEZE]:
     layer.trainable = False
  for layer in model.layers[NB_IV3_LAYERS_TO_FREEZE:]:
     layer.trainable = True
  model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


def train(args):
  """Use transfer learning and fine-tuning to train a network on a new dataset"""
  # nb_train_samples = get_nb_files(args.train_dir) #RC: don't believe this is needed
  nb_classes = len(glob.glob(args.train_dir + "/*"))
  validation_steps = get_nb_files(args.val_dir) #RC: use the entire validation data set to evaluate error/loss
  epochs = int(args.epochs)
  batch_size = int(args.batch_size)

  # data prep
  train_datagen =  ImageDataGenerator(
      preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
      rotation_range=30,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True
  )
  test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
      rotation_range=30,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True
  )

  # Takes the path to a directory, and generates batches of
  # augmented/normalized data
  train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    args.train_dir,
    # we specify the dimensions to which all images found will be resized
    # see https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/
    target_size=(IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT),
    batch_size=batch_size,
  )

  validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    args.val_dir,
    target_size=(IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT),
    batch_size=batch_size,
  )

  # setup model
  # use the flag include_top=False to leave out the weights of the last fully
  # connected layer since that is specific to the ImageNet competition, from
  # which the weights were previously trained
  base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False) #include_top=False excludes final FC layer
  model = add_new_last_layer(base_model, nb_classes)

  # transfer learning
  setup_to_transfer_learn(model, base_model)

  history_tl = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    epochs=epochs,
    steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH, # based on the original batch size of 32
                                # an epoch in training is 25,000. 25000/32 =  780
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=validation_steps,
    class_weight='auto')

  # fine-tuning
  setup_to_finetune(model)

  history_ft = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH, # based on the original batch size of 32
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=validation_steps,
    class_weight='auto')

  model.save(args.output_model_file)

  if args.plot:
    plot_training(history_ft)


def plot_training(history):
  acc = history.history['acc']
  val_acc = history.history['val_acc']
  loss = history.history['loss']
  val_loss = history.history['val_loss']
  epochs = range(len(acc))

  plt.plot(epochs, acc, 'r.')
  plt.plot(epochs, val_acc, 'r')
  plt.title('Training and validation accuracy')

  plt.figure()
  plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'r.')
  plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, 'r-')
  plt.title('Training and validation loss')
  plt.show()


if __name__=="__main__":
  a = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  a.add_argument("--train_dir")
  a.add_argument("--val_dir")
  a.add_argument("--epochs", default=EPOCHS)
  a.add_argument("--batch_size", default=BAT_SIZE)
  a.add_argument("--output_model_file", default="inceptionv3-ft.model")
  a.add_argument("--plot", action="store_true")

  args = a.parse_args()
  if args.train_dir is None or args.val_dir is None:
    a.print_help()
    sys.exit(1)

  if (not os.path.exists(args.train_dir)) or (not os.path.exists(args.val_dir)):
    print("directories do not exist")
    sys.exit(1)

  train(args)`
```

and the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transfer_learning_fine_tune_kerasV2.py", line 192, in <module>
    train(args)
  File "transfer_learning_fine_tune_kerasV2.py", line 125, in train
    model = add_new_last_layer(base_model, nb_classes)
  File "transfer_learning_fine_tune_kerasV2.py", line 56, in add_new_last_layer
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
  File "/Users/rchase/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 603, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rchase/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/pooling.py", line 536, in call
    return K.mean(inputs, axis=[1, 2])
  File "/Users/rchase/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1338, in mean
    if x.dtype.base_dtype == tf.bool:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem is with the line `x = base_model.outputs`. `base_model.outputs` is a list containing the output tensors of `base_model`, but `GlobalAveragePooling2D` expects a single tensor as its input.

```
print(base_model.outputs)
[<tf.Tensor 'mixed10/concat:0' shape=(?, ?, ?, 2048) dtype=float32>]

print(base_model.output)
Tensor("mixed10/concat:0", shape=(?, ?, ?, 2048), dtype=float32)
```

You can either change the line into `x = base_model.outputs[0]` or `x = base_model.output`. Both should work.